# Convert numpy array of 3*n*n images to 1*n*n?

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I have 800 images stored in numpy array of size (800, 3,256, 256), which I want to convert to (800, 1,256, 256).

I tried using cv2 library to achieve this but I am getting an error. What the easiest way to implement this?

```
train_img[i]= cv2.cvtColor(train_img[i], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
train_img[i]= cv2.cvtColor(train_img[i], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-82-e993ce67611f>", line 3, in <module>
    train_img[i]= cv2.cvtColor(train_img[i], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

error: C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11010: error: (-215) depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5 in function cv::cvtColor



OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11010
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11010
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11016
OpenCV Error: Bad number of channels (Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels) in cvConvertImage, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgcodecs\src\utils.cpp, line 622
OpenCV Error: Bad number of channels (Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels) in cvConvertImage, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgcodecs\src\utils.cpp, line 622
OpenCV Error: Bad number of channels (Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels) in cvConvertImage, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgcodecs\src\utils.cpp, line 622
OpenCV Error: Bad number of channels (Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels) in cvConvertImage, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgcodecs\src\utils.cpp, line 622
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11010
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11010
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11010
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11010
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11010
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11010
2020-11-19 05:55:59.003947: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-11-19 05:56:13.086709: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2020-11-19 05:56:13.088369: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-11-19 05:56:13.108395: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: DESKTOP-FAJP7DN
2020-11-19 05:56:13.109348: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: DESKTOP-FAJP7DN
2020-11-19 05:56:13.125396: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11010
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11010
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11010
```

Comment: Is it 3256 or 3 and 256

Comment: So in the second dimension you have 3 elements and your images are 256*256 pixels, correct me if wrong. In order to work with `cv2.cvtColor()` you need your array to be of the shape (256,256,3) for each image, not (3,256,256).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by [Elyas Karimi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64906007/convert-numpy-array-of-3nn-images-to-1nn#comment114753594_64906007) `cv2.cvtColor` expects the input images to be `256x256x3` and not `3x256x256`. You can [`transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) the images back and forth.
However, since converting from RGB to gray is a rather simple operation:

```
0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B
```

You can explicitly and efficiently do the conversion:

```py
# assuming your input is in BGR order
train_img = 0.289 * train_img[:, 2, ...] + 0.587 * train_img[:, 1, ...] + 0.114 * train_img[:, 0, ...]
```

In many cases the exact weight of each channel is not too critical, and a simple `mean` over channels can do just fine:

```
train_img = train_img.mean(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if i am wrong, you have images of `256*256` and they have 3 channels making it `256*256*3`
Now you want to make them one channeled as `256*26*1`.
By losing channel information, you are  converting RGB/BGR image into grey scale. Now to do that with OpenCV you will need to make them `256*256*3`, it wont work on `3*256*256`

So to do that lets take

```
 from numpy import moveaxis
 #image[i].shape=3*256*256
 data = moveaxis(image[i], 2, 0)
 #data.shape=256*256*3
```

Now pass this into OpenCv cvt.color

```
data= cv2.cvtColor(data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
data= cv2.cvtColor(data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

OR Use this

```
 data = 0.289 * data[:, 2, ...] + 0.587 * data[:, 1, ...] + 0.114 * data[:, 0, ...]
```